# iOS - Data from variables sent as email text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, email

I have a scorekeeping app that has variables for team names, score, etc.  I would like to be able to take the data stored in those variables and send it via email to whomever.  In other words, when the game is complete you can choose to send an email to a friend/family member with the team names and score already filled in the text of the email.  I would rather it not be sent as an attachment.  I know how to specify a subject and body, but not how to populate the body with the data from the app (which doesn't get stored).  The code I'm using:

```
    - (IBAction)email:(id)sender {
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"", nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@"Game Results Provided by Simple-Score"];
    [composer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
}
```

The problem I run into, my normal way of displaying an int which would be:

```
    [composer setMessageBody:@"%i", variable];
```

gives the error "no visible @interface for 'MFMailComposeViewController' declares the selector 'setMessageBody'" instead of the output i want.  If I enter static text in the  setMessageBody field, it displays fine.

Comment: I cannot see the problem. If you know how to specify message body, create NSString (perhaps HTML-formatted one) and populate it with the data.

Comment: Don't say things like "throws an error" on Stack Overflow without telling us what the error is.

Comment: Why do you expect every method to take a format string? Why don't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setMessageBody` doesn't take a format string as an argument, so this is wrong:

```
[composer setMessageBody:@"%i", variable];
```

It takes an `NSString` object as an argument, so you want something like this:

```
[composer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", variable]];
```

Obviously assuming that `variable` is the right type.

Comment: Thanks Jim, this is what I needed and somehow missed.